# MongoDB: slug is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Each schema has `slug` of its own. `mongoose-slug-generator` generates slug for `schemaMain` but for `schema1` the slug is `undefined`.

Unable to understand why is it undefined.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const { Schema } = mongoose
var slug = require("mongoose-slug-generator");
mongoose.plugin(slug);

const schema1 = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 40,
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        slug: ["name"],
        slug_padding_size: 4
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        min: 1,
        max: 200,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    video: {},
    music: []
}, { timestamps: true })


const schemaMain = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 40,
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        slug: ["name"],
        unique: true,
        slug_padding_size: 4
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        min: 1,
        max: 200,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    schemas: [schema1],
}, { timestamps: true })

export default mongoose.model('SomeModel', schemaMain)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `mongoose-slug-generator` use `mongoose-slug-updater`

What you have is nested schemas, and `mongoose-slug-updater` works well for the same.

Example of Nested Schemas declared separately

```
const SubChildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  slug: { type: String, slug: 'title' },
  absoluteRootSlug: { type: String, slug: '/title' },
  absoluteChildSlug: { type: String, slug: '/child.title' },
  relativeParentSlug: { type: String, slug: ':title' },// child's title
  relativeGrandParentSlug: { type: String, slug: '::title' },//parent's title
});

const ChildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  subChild: SubChildSchema,
  subChildren: [SubChildSchema],
  slug: { type: String, slug: 'title' },
  subChildSlug: { type: String, slug: 'subChild.title' },
  absoluteSlug: { type: String, slug: '/child.title' },
  absoluteRootSlug: { type: String, slug: '/title' },
  relativeParentSlug: { type: String, slug: ':title' },//Parent
  subChildrenSlug2: { type: String, slug: 'subChildren.2.title' },
  subChildrenSlug3: { type: String, slug: 'subChildren.3.title' },
});

const ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  child: ChildSchema,
  children: [ChildSchema],
  slug: { type: String, slug: 'title' },
  absoluteSlug: { type: String, slug: '/title' },
  childSlug: { type: String, slug: 'child.title' },
  absoluteChildSlug: { type: String, slug: '/child.title' },
  subChildSlug: { type: String, slug: 'child.subChild.title' },
  childrenSlug0: { type: String, slug: 'children.0.title' },
  childrenSlug4: { type: String, slug: 'children.4.title' },
  subChildrenSlug3: { type: String, slug: 'children.7.subChildren.3.title' },
  subChildrenSlug7: { type: String, slug: 'children.3.subChildren.7.title' },
});
```

You may read more about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-slug-updater)